# Sonata custom field in admin class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I created a new field type and I am trying to use it in sonata. 
In one of my admin classes I have the following:

```
$formMapper
                    ->add('name', 'text')
                    ->add('img_home', new \MyBundle\Form\Type\ImageType(), array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'label' => 'home set image',
                        'attr' => array('src' => '/' . $home)
                            )
                    )
```

When I do this on the img_home field I trigger this exception

'Please define a type for field ...'

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/blob/master/Builder/FormContractor.php#L56

If I comment out this exception everything works fine. I see the field I want without any issues.

How can I fix this without having to change the code?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution.
After reading the code I noticed that there is a 4th argument you can pass and sonatas code checks if the array passed has they 'type' key.
So I just added :

```
array('type' => 'string')
```

As the 4th parameter

Comment: Its better to use sonata media bundle for all your file types

Comment: I just started using sonata and so far the documentation has been horrible. If there are good examples of how to use this bundle I am all for it, otherwise I prefer to just do my own stuff.